# Knot path effect in Inkscape 1.0 -- is there a bug?

Tags: inkscape

While using the recently released [Inkscape 1.0](https://inkscape.org/release/inkscape-1.0/?latest=1), I realized that the "Knot" path effect is not working as it was before. When I click any yellow diamond on a crossing, it wouldn't change the crossing. (See the screenshots below.) It changes the blue circular arrow, though I am not sure what change it really makes to the image. Am I missing something, or is it just a bug that should be fixed?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Unfortunately tech support questions are off topic here. Sorry about that. Anyway, it looks like you might have discovered a bug. I tested in 0.92 where it's working and also in 1.00 on a copy of the same path. In 1.00, the strokes [don't interweave](https://imgur.com/HJCqN3J) as they do in 0.92.

Comment: Yes, it's a known issue and it is fixed for 1.0.1. Please report bugs at https://inkscape.org/report instead of here.

Comment: I have the same problem, have you find a solution?

Comment: @NicolaMedici Not in ver 1.0. Instead, I simply downloaded an older version of the program where there was no such bug.